# Extracting some Text in a png with Py tesseract

Tags: python, ocr

i try to extract the Texts of each Card,
[image]
so far i tried simply reading the image and extract the text with pytesseract,but i just return like 1 word of all the text in the image:
( Spirit of Fire i Suzumebochity

Momomo
code:

```
im=cv2.imread(impath)
text=pytesseract.image_to_string(im)
print(text)
```

someone got any ideas what i can do to improve it?
maybe some advice, what to change and maybe a how i can properly extract the texts for each card

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:
https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/

It suggests you are missing the BGR to RGB conversion i.e.

```
import cv2

img_cv = cv2.imread(r'/<path_to_image>/digits.png')

# By default OpenCV stores images in BGR format and since pytesseract assumes RGB format,
# we need to convert from BGR to RGB format/mode:
img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img_cv, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img_rgb))
# OR
img_rgb = Image.frombytes('RGB', img_cv.shape[:2], img_cv, 'raw', 'BGR', 0, 0)
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img_rgb))
```